# Formal way of saying "chickens out"

Tags: slang

I am writing an essay, and I need to find a formal word that means the same thing as chickens out. The context in which I use it is "Eckels chickens out of hunting the dinosaur and he runs back to the time machine."

I am using in the context that the person can do go through with the thing they were doing because of fear. 
Is there any single word in the English language that means the same thing?

A few words are fine, but a single word is better.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a sentence where you are going to use the word?

Comment: in your question: the person can go through with the thing they were doing even though fearsome or cannot go through because of fear?

Comment: Demur, a word I still use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Eckels **quailed** at the idea of hunting the dinosaur and he ran back to the time machine."

> - quail - (verb) - to shrink back in fear; cower. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/quail)

You might also use "lost courage".

Comment: Thank you. Since it has to be in present tense, is "Eckels quails at the idea of hunting the dinosaur and he runs back to the time machine" correct?

Answer (score 2):

[To lose one’s nerve](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lose+one%27s+nerve) is still idiomatic but much more formal than *chicken out*.

> David had wanted to jump off the top diving board at the swimming pool, but lost his nerve once up there.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use 'to regreat' to refer that the person is chickening out about the act

Comment: Regreat? Are you sure.

Comment: It depends on you and your sentence, you can say "I was trying to tell her about my feelings but when I arrived to her house I regretted and came back to the car"

Comment: You might want to check your spelling. Make a correction and I'll delete my comments here.